# Python return which list items string contains

Tags: python, string, list, any

I have a list of words and a string like so:

```
wordlist = ['fox', 'over', 'lazy']
paragraph = 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox.'
```

I want to know which words in the list occur in the string and return them. Is there some relatively clever way to do this?

For example, `any(word in paragraph for word in wordlist)` only returns `True` or `False`, but not the actual words that were found.

Comment: `[word for word in wordlist if word in paragraph]` gives you the list, is that what you want?

Comment: `set(paragraph.strip('.').split()).intersection(wordlist)`

Comment: @Kasramvd that's a little fragile - what if the `paragraph` consists of more than a single sentence, or ends with punctuation other than a full stop?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, It just works for this case. in that case OP has to find the words with regex.

Comment: @Piwwoli, should `jump` be matched  if `jumped` is in the paragraph?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes. Do you have a solution for the "No-case" though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your test in a list comprehension:

```
words_in_paragraph = [word for word in wordlist if word in paragraph]
```

This moved the test for the `any()` generator to the end.

Demo:

```
>>> wordlist = ['fox', 'over', 'lazy']
>>> paragraph = 'A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox.'
>>> [word for word in wordlist if word in paragraph]
['fox', 'over', 'lazy']
>>> another_wordlist = ['over', 'foo', 'quick']
>>> [word for word in another_wordlist if word in paragraph]
['over', 'quick']
```

Note that, just like your `any()` test, this'll work for *partial* word matches too, of course:

```
>>> partial_words = ['jump', 'own']
>>> [word for word in partial_words if word in paragraph]
['jump', 'own']
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter

```
included_words = filter(lambda word: word in paragraph, wordlist)
```

Although in python3, this would generate an iterator, so if you want a list use list comprehension approach (or you can just call list on filter result if you prefer), otherwise iterator would do just fine.

```
included_words = list(filter(lambda word: word in paragraph, wordlist))
```

OR

```
included_words = [word for word in wordlist if word in paragraph]
```

Comment: This will not produce a list in Python 3; a filter iterator object is returned instead.